# Assign value to Var in C# using try catch

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, anonymous-methods

I want to do something like this in C#. I think this is possible using Delegates or Anonymous Methods. I tried but I couldn't do it. Need help.

```
SomeType someVariable = try {
                          return getVariableOfSomeType();
                        } catch { Throw new exception(); }
```

Comment: It makes sense to me. Evaluate an expression as usual, except that if the evaluation of the expression results an exception, the exception gets caught. A C# `try` statement can only contain statements, and cannot return a value.

Comment: @hvd  : Thank you ! 

Never thought of this : - 
"try statement can only contain statements, and cannot return a value"

Comment: @geedubb : 
Probably it would have been helpful if you have elaborately explained why code or question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic helper function:

```
static T TryCatch<T, E>(Func<T> func, Func<E, T> exception)
  where E : Exception {
  try {
    return func();
  } catch (E ex) {
    return exception(ex);
  }
}
```

which you can then call like so:

```
static int Main() {
  int zero = 0;
  return TryCatch<int, DivideByZeroException>(() => 1 / zero, ex => 0);
}
```

This evaluates `1 / zero` within the context of `TryCatch`'s `try`, causing the exception handler to be evaluated which simply returns 0.

I doubt this will be more readable than a helper variable and `try`/`catch` statements directly in `Main`, but if you have situations where it is, this is how you can do it.

Instead of `ex => 0`, you can also make the exception function throw something else.

Comment: This is more suited for F#.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with F#, but [looking at the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233194.aspx), it seems like you're right, F# already supports this natively. Good to know.

Comment: Pattern matching is a beautiful thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
SomeType someVariable;
try {
  someVariable = getVariableOfSomeType();
}
catch {
  throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeType someVariable = null;

try
{
    someVariable = GetVariableOfSomeType();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // Do something with exception

    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeType someVariable = null;

try
{
    //try something, if fails it move to catch exception
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // Do something with exception

    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What about restructuring the code?

Instead of this:

```cs
SomeType someVariable = try {
                          return getVariableOfSomeType();
                        } catch
```

Put all the code which relies on the variable **within the try block**:

```cs
                        try {
                          SomeType someVariable = getVariableOfSomeType();
                          perform_calculation(some_variable); // <---- all code here
                        } catch
```

The point I am making is: consider restructuring your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
try 
{
    SomeType someVariable = return getVariableOfSomeType();
} 
catch { throw; }
```